# Script to return file as string

Tags: javascript, php, html, string

What I am trying to do is very simple, but I am haveing problems to make it work...
It is basically a text on a html page that changes according to the text that exists on a different html file.

Main html file:

```
<html> 
<body>
       <label for="Order2" id="Order2"> </label>
       <script>
           var Order2 = returnedfromthephpfile;
           document.getElementById('Order2').innerHTML = Order2;
       </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my php file:

```
<?php
    $src = fopen('C:\\Order.html', 'r');
    return $src;
    fclose($src);
?>
```

The other html file:

```
<TABLE BORDER="0" cellpadding="0" CELLSPACING="0"><TR><TD WIDTH="360" HEIGHT="190" VALIGN="top">Hello</TD></TR></TABLE>
```

Does anyone knows how can I do this, or if there is a easier way to do it?

Comment: Changes how, why would the text change, and how would one page know what's going on on the other page. It's not as simple as you probably think it is.

Comment: Your php is fairly off-base.  Rather than `fopen`, use `file_get_contents`.  And rather than `return`, use `echo $src;` - ASSUMING that you're making an AJAX call (which is implied, but not clear)

Comment: Thank for all the answers here.

Do you have any exemple of the AJAX call I should use where is written retirnedfromthphpfile ?


Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use file_get_contents to get the contents of a file into a string.
https://www.php.net/file_get_contents

```
$src = file_get_contents("path_to_file.txt")
```